# The authentication in visual studio code gets cancelled

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have done on the coding part in visual studio code while using command palette to download symbols i can't able to download it rather in output it displays about the authentication has failed. How to solve that one ?

Comment: Could you try to explain what you have done, what you are trying to do, and what is going wrong in more detail?

Comment: Yes sir/madam, I am using visual studio code with AL Language  which connects Business Central Dynamics 365 when I'm done the coding for page and table creation and extension after when I give download symbols using command palette,In output i receive the error known please authenticate in the vs.code .. authentication has been cancelled ...and also I can't able to publish it ..could you help me out of this ?